# What is the equivalent of $this->withoutExceptionHandling() in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

So, i'm writing tests using laravel 8.8. In other previous versions, while testing i could write `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` to bubble up the exact error and know how to tackle it. i'm having issues doing the same with version 8.8.

My Code.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

use App\Models\User;

class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    /**
     * Test if it checks for validation at the point of registarion.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testValidationDuringRegistration()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->post('/api/v1/register', ['Accept' => 'application/json']);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(406)
            ->assertJsonValidationErrors(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']);
    }

    /**
     * Test if it checks for validation at the point of registarion.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testValidationIfSomeRequiredFieldsAreFilled()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->post('/api/v1/register', [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'first_name' => 'test',
            'last_name' => 'test_last_name'
            ]);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(406)
            ->assertJsonMissingValidationErrors(['first_name', 'last_name']);
    }

    public function testIfRegistrationIsSuccessful()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->post('/api/v1/register', [
            User::factory()->create()
        ]);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

My UserFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'lastname' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

Test result

```
 FAIL  Tests\Feature\AuthenticationTest
  ⨯ if registration is successful

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\AuthenticationTest > if registration is successful
  Expected status code 200 but received 406.
  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 406.

  at tests/Feature/AuthenticationTest.php:58
     54▕             User::factory()->create()
     55▕         ]);
     56▕ 
     57▕         $response
  ➜  58▕             ->assertStatus(200);
     59▕     }
     60▕ }
     61▕ 


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   5.66s
```

Handler.php

```
/**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->renderable(function (\AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
            // return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
            return response()->json([
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => 'Unauthenticated.',
            ], 403);
        });

        $this->renderable(function (\ModelNotFoundException $e, $request) {
            return response()->json([
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => 'Resource could not be found.',
            ], 403); 
        });

        $this->renderable(function (\ArgumentCountError $e, $request) {
            return response()->json([
                'success'   => false,
                'message'   => 'Please provide required url parameters.',
            ], 403); 
        });
    }
```

The above test keeps failing, but i can't seem to know why. I just need a way to output the real error messages, so i can move forward.

Thanks

I'm using Laravel version 8.8